# python ssh without authenticity validation

Tags: python, ssh

I am running a command remotely on an AWS machine like this:

```
key = 'myPemFile.pem'
target = <machine_ip>
cmd = 'ssh -i ' + key + ' ubuntu@'+target+' "nohup myprog + ' >& /dev/null < /dev/null &" &'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This works fine, but if it is the first login onto the machine I get the question:

```
The authenticity of host '144.224.18.97 (144.224.18.97)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is e2:4e:...:e3:73:07.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)
```

how do I "input" "yes" from python, or alternatively, use a flag to tell ssh not to ask the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to pass -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no to the ssh command.

Comment: Hmm... getting 
"command-line line 0: Missing yes/no/ask argument."

Comment: I edited the question with your siuggestion. Still does not work.

Comment: One thing to note: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No (or Yes) will present a 'bad yes/no/ask argument'.  The value must be all lower-case.  Broke some of my scripts before so I thought I'd mention it in case it helps someone else.